# Android : cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header is not importing

Tags: android, apache, http-headers, apache-httpclient-4.x, loopj

I am trying call an API by using `loopj` library.Because I want to totally avoid `org.apache.http.legacy` method for calling API.

So I add the dependency for the `loopj` and build the project

```
 compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
```

`loopj` is successfully build, but when i try to call `Header` for the `AsyncHttpResponseHandler`  `org.apache.http.Header[] headers` is automatically import instead of `cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header`

```
    AsyncHttpClient clientloop = new AsyncHttpClient();

     clientloop.get("http://www.google.com",new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
         @Override
         public void onSuccess(int i, org.apache.http.Header[] headers, byte[] bytes) {

         }

         @Override
         public void onFailure(int i, org.apache.http.Header[] headers, byte[] bytes, Throwable throwable) {

         }
     });
```

can anyone please help me to avoid the calling of `org.apache.http`

Answer (score 3):

Add this dependency in gradle `compile 'cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.3.6'`

after that check the import on class, it should like this `import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;`

Comment: this is awesome!